# How to set up OneDrive on Ubuntu 16.04LTS?

Tags: 16.04, sync

I tried the guides but a window never popped up prompting me to sign in, so I continued with the command 'onedrive-pref'. That did nothing, so now I have a [`OneDrive`](https://skilion.github.io/onedrive/) folder and a `.onedrive` folder.

I checked my OneDrive account online; there was no new files/folders. I'm trying to get it to where I have a folder in my home folder that will sync with OneDrive online.

Comment: which guides you tried?

Comment: All of them.  Searched onedrive on ubuntu and went to these websites askubuntu.com    howtogeek.com   maketecheasier.com   omgubuntu.co.uk

Comment: there is no official client for one drive on ubuntu. there is a paid software that has a 15 days trial. I am using it for more than two years and it works perfectly.

Comment: https://www.insynchq.com/pricing?grsf=gt7jqj 
you can have a look at it at the given link. you will get a 5usd discount as well

Answer (score 0):

I've just found suitaible way of accessing and mounting OneDrive in Ubuntu 16.04 with Rclone-Browser

1) 
Downlouad the Rclone program here and install it on your system: (the version in the standard Ubuntu repository only works for Onedrive personal edition.)
https://rclone.org/downloads/   or directly from this for Ubuntu 64 bit systems: https://downloads.rclone.org/rclone-current-linux-amd64.deb

```
sudo dpkg -i rclone-current-linux-amd64.deb
```

2) Rclone-browser

Download the rclonebrowser form here: https://github.com/mmozeiko/RcloneBrowser/releases
or install via a ppa (not yet for ubuntu  18.04)
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mmozeiko/rclone-browser
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install rclone-browser
After installing both packages, start rclone-browser from the dash.

[image]

> select n for new remote and give it any name that suits you. Onedrive would be fine.

Select 18 Onedrive (number can change)

leave blank twice

select personal or business

select Y if you are running a normal desktop system.

Now the browser should open and you can login in your onedrive account

now return to the terminal and conform with Y

press Q to exit and return to the rclone-browser and press the refresh button.

> Now you should see your onedrive account and  you can open it by double clicking

You are now able to mount it and see it in Nautilus. It is NOT a locally available filesystem. It is still remote. Some programs can read and write to this remote drive, and some don't. A workaround is to open a secon TAB in Nautilus, copy the files you need to the second TAB. Use them from there and copy them back afterwards.

Source:
[Rclone and Rclone-Browser](https://sites.google.com/site/installationubuntu/home/ubuntu-17-10/cloud-storage)